# Interlocked Concurrent loop oddity

Tags: c#, concurrency

So, I have this code:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Bar foo = new Bar();
        ConcurrentBag<int> items = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
        const int times = 200;
        Parallel.For(0, times, i=>{
            foreach(var j in foo.RequestValues(times)){
                items.Add(j);
            }
        });
        Dictionary<int, int> frequency = new Dictionary<int,int>();
        foreach (var item in items){
            if (!frequency.ContainsKey(item)){
                frequency[item] = 0;
            }
            else{
                frequency[item]++;
            }
        }
        foreach(var pair in frequency){
            Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + " occurred " + pair.Value + "times.");
        }
    }
    class Bar{
        const int max = 20;
        int val = -1;
        internal int[] RequestValues(int count){
            int[] result = new int[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++){
                int read;
                while ((read = Interlocked.Add(ref val, 1)) >= max){
                    int check = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref val, 0, read);
                    if (check == 0){
                        read = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                result[i] = read;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run it, I get an output like this:

```
3 occurred 2098times.
2 occurred 2098times.
1 occurred 2098times.
19 occurred 2098times.
18 occurred 2098times.
17 occurred 2098times.
16 occurred 2098times.
15 occurred 2098times.
14 occurred 2098times.
13 occurred 2098times.
12 occurred 2098times.
11 occurred 2098times.
10 occurred 2098times.
9 occurred 2098times.
0 occurred 118times.
```

I am absolutely boggled by 0 only happening 118 times instead of 2098 times. Is there a reason for this? Could someone explain this to me?

Edit: It appears the TLDR answer is "`Interlocked.CompareExchange` returns the old value", in which case, how do I know the value was swapped? The value might have been changed by another thread before I can get to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It becomes a lot clearer when you ignore the threading part of the code. Replacing your `Parallel.For` with the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= times; i++)
{
    foreach(var j in foo.RequestValues(times))
    {
        items.Add(j);
    }
}
```

Shows `0` has having `0` occurrences. But debugging, it's clear that there should be at least *one* entry, since the loop is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++){
```

The problem is `frequency[item] = 0;` (should be `= 1;`). So now we're getting `1` occurrence correctly, but that still doesn't answer your question.

So why is that so?

Look at this code, in a non-threaded context:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++){
    int read;
    while ((read = Interlocked.Add(ref val, 1)) >= max){
        int check = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref val, 0, read);
        if (check == 0){
            read = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    result[i] = read;
}
```

When will `read` ever be `0`? There are two places we change `read`:

`while ((read = Interlocked.Add(ref val, 1)) >= max){`

and

`read = 0;`

The first one will only ever give us a value of `0` when `val` is `-1`. (Which is only at the very beginning of the program).

The second line sets it to `0`, but in a serialized context, it will never execute, as `CompareExchange` returns the current value of `val` (which is going to be when it's `>= max`).

So let's go back to the context of threads.

`CompareExchange` *can* return `0`, but only if `val` has changed between our increment and our compare. What situation would it return `0`?

Whenever `val = 0`. And `val` will only be 0 when `read = val` - and only on the previous execution.

So the steps to have `read = 0` Are as follows:

1. Two threads must enter the `while` (`val > 20`)
2. One thread blocks before executing `CompareExchange`.
3. The other thread executes `CompareExchange` (`val` is now set to `0`)
4. That first thread then executes `CompareExchange` and has `check` set to 0.

Note that if any other thread modifies `val` while this is happening, `check` will not be `0`. It essentially requires two threads to be perfectly in sync for `read` to ever be set to 0. And it's very easy for other threads to disrupt the flow.

---

**Edit**

In regards to the following question:

> @BrainStorm.exe: Ok, in that case, how do I know the value was set to 0? In java, the compare and swap for AtomicInteger returns a bool so I can know, but how would I know here?

You'd know if it were set by comparing `check == read` (if this is true, then you can be sure that `CompareExchange` actually modified `val`). This works in your situation, as `read` is not shared between threads. Note, though, that checking `val` immediately after `CompareExchange` does not guarantee that `val` is still 0

Comment: Right... It appears it returns the old value XD. I thought that would return the new value since `Interlocked.Add` returns the new value. It appears that is not the case...

Comment: Yep - it returns the old value since you're passing in the new value. In the case of `Add`, we don't know what the new value will be - we only know how much it's been incremented by

Comment: Ok, in that case, how do I know the value was set to 0? In java, the compare and swap for `AtomicInteger` returns a bool so I can know, but how would I know here?

Comment: You'd know if it were set by comparing `check == read` (if this is true, then you can be sure that `CompareExchange` actually modified `val`). This works in your situation, as `read` is not shared between threads. Note, though, that checking `val` immediately after `CompareExchange` does not guarantee that `val` is still 0.